# How to change the separator for group data in formCollection in MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a form in view with dynamic row with fields bound to viewmodel like:

```
 <%for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
 { %>
   <tr> 
    <td style="width: 100%">
      <%= Html.TextBox("Link", Model.Websites[i.ToString()].Links)%>
     </td>
      .....
   </tr>
 <%} %>
```

When the form is posted, in FormCollection, all data coming from TextBox "Link" is a string separated by comma,.  like, Yahoo.com, youtube.com, google.com

Then I can use comma to extract the data to array like:

```
string[] links = formdata["Link"].Split(',');
```

But question is: if the data use entered include comma, like "mysite, go.com", the I can get the right data for each item.

How to resolve this issue? is it possible to set special separator for string in FormCollection?

Comment: "all data coming from TextBox 'Link' is a string separated by comma,. like, Yahoo.com, youtube.com, google.com". That is a false premise. Your question can't be answered, because its premise is incorrect. Look in Firebug or Fiddler.

Comment: Hi, here "Yahoo.com", "youtube.com", "google.com" are example the data entered in text box, not means something for those site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
public ActionResult MyActionToHandleForm(string[] Link)
{
}
```

You should automatically get correct array. Read [here](http://marcomagdy.com/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-form-inputs-to-action-parameters/) for more.

Notice that you may also be able to do (name textbox "Link[i]")

```
 <%for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
 { %>
   <tr> 
    <td style="width: 100%">
      <%= Html.TextBox("Link[" + i + "]", Model.Websites[i.ToString()].Links)%>
     </td>
      .....
   </tr>
 <%} %>
```

with the same string[] Link action input parameter, but in this case you'll be sure to get correct strings for correct indices (even if, for example, you hide some of them).